# Rewrite .php to display .htm

Tags: php, html

I want to show a .php file as a .htm extension. This is what I thought would work, but it doesn't:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^contact\.php$ contact.htm [NC,R,L]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close. You have got the rewrite rule parameters reversed - the first parameter is what you are listening for (content.html) and the second is what you want to load instead (contact.php). I have also removed the `R` flag so the server does this internally - with the `R` flag the server will send a command to the browser to force it redirect to the new location.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^contact\.htm$ contact.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your .htaccess file to allow PHP in HTML files:

```
# allow HTML files to process PHP
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm

# now the rewrite can occur
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^contact\.htm$ contact.php [NC,R,L]
```

With that in there you can rewrite the URL.

Comment: I do not understand this way to be honest. Thought it would make more sense to do a single page rewrite in the .htaccess file?

Comment: @user3642210 This basically tells Apache to treat every `.htm` or `.html` file as a PHP file and pass it through the interpreter - it would work but it's not exactly efficient... especially as you're only wanting to fake one single filename.

Comment: Yep - @CD001 is right, it is not very efficient at all. My preference is to rewrite and exclude file extensions.